# How to allow outbound traffic with UFW?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

Ubuntu 10.04 | VPS

Hi guys, I'm setting up a VPS server running Ubuntu 10.04 and I presently just want to allow ssh.

I thought the following ufw commands would work...

```
ufw default deny
ufw allow 22
ufw allow from <local IP of vps>
ufw enable
```

SSH works fine.  But established sessions seem to be blocked -- the vps host can't ping other servers, perform DNS queries, etc.  How do I tell ufw that it's OK for the server to send OUTBOUND requests anywhere while still remaining protected?

---

In response to andol's question, here are the results of `ufw status verbose`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10022                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    <local IP>
```

Obviously the second rule is wrong so I deleted it and the problem still persists.

Comment: What does "ufw status verbose" give you?

Comment: @andol Output in description.

Comment: The default "allow (outgoing)" should really take care of just that. Does everything work as it should when you disable ufw on the VPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Apparently, UFW doesn't work well with OpenVZ hosts... more info here: http://blog.bodhizazen.net/uncategorized/how-to-use-ufw-in-openvz-templates/

Comment: Yeah, once you leave userspace a OpenVZ guest can behave a bit special...